# Shortcode return $content vs do_shortcode($content)

Tags: shortcode

I think the title of my question says it all.

When creating a shortcode, I've seen some people do `do_shortcode($content)` instead of `$content`.

What is the difference?

Another thing, let's say I have a shortcode `[hello]World[/hello]`. Wouldn't returning `do_shortcode($content)` result in `do_shortcode('World')`?

From the codex, the examples given are as such, `do_shortcode('[hello]')`

So what will returning `do_shortcode($content)` interpret? (in the case of `[hello]`)

Any practical examples or clear explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is useful if you don’t know if the `$content` contains unknown shortcodes.

Example

**Your shortcode**

```
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'shortcode_foo' );

function shortcode_foo(  $atts, $content = '' )
{
    return 'Foo!' . do_shortcode( $content );
}
```

Now your user might write something like this:

```
[foo][bar][/foo]
```

You have no idea what `[bar]` does or that it even exists. So you let WordPress handle that per `do_shortcode()`. If you don’t do that, `[bar]` will not be parsed as shortcode and showed as is instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Am I safe to say it's best practice to return do_shortcode($content)?

Comment: @Bobby That depends on what you want to do with the content. If you don’t care, then yes, you should.